# Android saving image in system gallery

Tags: android, image, android-gallery

I am trying to modify image loaded from system gallery and save new version of that image on SD card.
Problem is that saved image is placed at the end of gallery (tested on branded Galaxy Ace 2 and CyanogenMod 7 on Galaxy Ace).

Any idea what is responsible for position of newly saved image?

I've tried even get code from CyanogenMod, but it didn't work.

Comment: It is not clear what exactly you want to accomplish...

Comment: I am talking about position of newly saved image in gallery application. When I take a new photo, image is saved at the beginning of image list in gallery app. If I save image using my code, image is placed at the end of gallery app. Is it still unclear?